# Look at object in OpenGL

Tags: c++, trigonometry, glm-math

In 2d plane I can get an object face another by calculating the `atan2` of their x and y position difference, and rotating the object by that angle. In 3d space I'm thinking I need to calculate angles for 3 planes instead of 1.

Is there a function in GLM that does this you for you automatically?

Comment: I assume you're talking about [GLM](https://glm.g-truc.net), not [GLM](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/glm/info) or [GLM](http://devernay.free.fr/hacks/glm/)?

Comment: `glm::lookAt` gives you exactly the transformation matrix @httpdigest talked about.

Comment: `glm::lookAt` gives the inverse of what you want so you need to take the inverse to get what you want. <rant> This is arguably a common poor design of 3D math libraries. There is rarely more than one view matrix per frame but there can easily be 20, 30, 100 things you want to "look at" something else so ideally if you're only going to have one lookAt function it should return a camera matrix (a matrix that points something at something else in world space), not a view matrix (a matrix that moves the entire world relative to the camera). http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/8x1q8tn7/

Comment: @gman: "*There is rarely more than one view matrix per frame but there can easily be 20, 30, 100 things you want to "look at" something else*" And yet, every application has that one view, while there are plenty of applications that don't need "look at" functionality. Or at least, not in this way. This is particularly true for anything with animation. If the angle between the current orientation and the desired look at direction is large, you need to rotate it over time so that it looks at the target. A "look at" function isn't very helpful in this regard.

Comment: Many applications don't use lookAt to generate a view matrix. Pretty much every 3d editor and most major game engines put the camera in their scene graph so to get a view matrix they take the inverse of the world matrix of the camera. There are plenty of other places you might need a real "lookAt" matrix instead of a view matrix where as the one time you need the opposite you could easily do `inverse(lookAt)`.

Comment: Why do I need to use `glm::inverse(glm::lookAt)` in this case and not`glm::lookAt`? Haven't had success with implementing it as of yet. For some reason the eye object doesn't stay in one place. I used `glm::lookAt(eye, target, up)`.

Answer (score 0):

@gman had the answer I was looking for, I just had to do glm::inverse(glm::lookat()) to solve my problem!

Comment: Turning a comment into an answer is welcome. You can improve by providing all the useful information in an explained and nicely structured and formatted way. Just keep your attribution to credit the helpful user. Have fun.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34178852)